# Passing self into a constructor in python

Tags: python, this, self

I recently was working on a little python project and came to a situation where I wanted to pass `self` into the constructor of another object. I'm not sure why, but I had to look up whether this was legal in python. I've done this many times in C++ and Java but I don't remember ever having to do this with python.

Is passing references to `self` to new objects something that isn't considered *pythonic*? I don't think I've seen any python programs explicitly passing self references around. Have I just happen to not have a need for it until now? Or am I fighting python style?

Comment: Um, few things are unpythonic *per se*, it's just that there are *usually* better approaches (whether on a design or implementation level). Your questions doesn't name the problem, so we can't judge whether your solution is any good.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I have to agree, this doesn't get done as much in Python as in e.g. Java. No idea why, though.

Comment: I don't know why people insist on saying "pythonic" when they simply mean "clean", but there's nothing inherently wrong with this.  Just watch out for circular references and `__del__`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it is legal, and yes it is pythonic.

I find myself using this pattern when you have an object and a container object where the contained objects need to know about their parent.

Comment: Yeah I understand why you need to do it, but I'm just not sure why I haven't seen it done very much in python.

Comment: Possibly because python has a wicked set of polymorphic container types which in general are sufficient for all your needs?

Comment: Can adapter pattern be considered one of the uses, I mean if we don't consider parameter to be passed as *self* but another object instance which has to be contained.

Comment: @Nick - I’m pretty late to the party here, but please could you explain what you mean by polymorphic container types, and why they are relevant?

Answer (score 4):

Just pass it like a parameter.  Of course, it won't be called `self` in the other initializer...

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, num, target):
        self.num = num
        self.target = target

class B:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.a = A(num, self)

a = A(1)
b = B(2)
print b.a.num # prints 2
```

Comment: I think this is more or less asking whether its _pythonic_, not how.

Comment: super confusing.